# How can I get the data of my status_content column?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a status/post. I have 4 fields in my table(post) id, user_id, status_time and status_content. I want to get the data on my status_content of 1 user_id only, can someone help me?

For example:

I have 3 users

user 1 = posted 3times

user 2 = posted 2times

user 3 = posted 5times

How can i only get all the data posted by user 3?

Sorry for my english.

**Code to send data to my database**

profile.php

```
if(isset($_POST['status_content'])){
        $status_content = $_POST['status_content'];
        if(!empty($_POST['status_content'])){
        add_status($_SESSION['accts_id'], $status_time, $status_content);
    }
}
```

core.php

```
function add_status($accts_id, $status_time, $status_content){
$sql = "INSERT INTO `post` (user_id, status_time, status_content) VALUES ('$accts_id', '$status_time', '$status_content')";
mysql_query($sql);}
```

Comment: you can use sql query like  `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE user_id='3'`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this as follows

to get data particularly for user 3 then

```
select status_content from post where user_id = '3'
```

to get data for any users

```
select status_content from post where user_id = $_SESSION['accts_id'];
```

[**UPDATED**]

Comment: I mean, I only wanted to get the data from `status_content` column.